# Hosting Smart Contracts in Azure BlockChain

Tags: azure, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I am trying to deploy smart contracts built using solidity extension for visual studio to ethereum blockchain in azure.

Following this blog for startup of the visual studio code

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/caleteet/2016/04/01/solidity-integration-with-visual-studio/

I have added "Ethereum blockchain leader" in azure and it's working

Currently Sample contract looks like ..

```
contract Payout {
 address Victor;
 address Jim;
 address Kieren;

 mapping (address => uint) ownershipDistribution; 

 function Setup() {
   Victor = 0xaabb;
   Jim    = 0xccdd;
   Kieren = 0xeeff;

   ownershipDistribution[Victor] = 35;
   ownershipDistribution[Jim]  = 35;
   ownershipDistribution[Kieren] = 30;
 }

 function Dividend() {
   uint bal= this.balance;
   Victor.send(bal * ownershipDistribution[Victor] / 100); 
   Jim.send(bal * ownershipDistribution[Jim] / 100);
   Kieren.send(bal * ownershipDistribution[Kieren] / 100);
 }
}
```

When I compile smartcontract, it is compiled ok. but when i deploy to azure ethereum

contract gets deployed but i get the error
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"EOF"}}